# Can I use transactions to ensure consistent walk through my records with repeated SELECTs using OFFSET and LIMIT?

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, backend

I have a scheduled job that runs once a day, synchronizing entities between multiple APIs. I'm looking for a reliable way to pull "pages" of data from my DB, without downloading GBs worth of it in one go, using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`.

From what I understand, starting a transaction at the beginning of the process and executing repeated `SELECT`s within it will ensure that no records in my result set are added or skipped due to other concurrent processes?

Hopefully, that would allow me to perform the synchronization job on the exact state of DB records at the start of the transaction. Also, it may be worth to know that the sync job itself won't alter the records from said result set.

Comment: The transaction isolation level determines what queries will see. Based on your description, you'll need repeatable read or serializable levels

Comment: Use repeatable read: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Burak Serdar and Frank Heikens have pointed out, a repeatable read isolation level was the solution, easily achieved by starting a transaction with the required option (using `sqlx`):

```
tx, err := DB.BeginTxx(ctx, &sql.TxOptions{
    Isolation: sql.LevelRepeatableRead,
    ReadOnly:  true,
})
```